WDL workflow with docker image does not work in M1 chip
I'm trying to run a very simple WDL workflow just an Rscript that prints when a library is loaded.
This is a very minimal example since I was able to figure out that what is causing the issue is actually running the dockerImage built for linux/amd in a M1 chip MacOS. My script is below and I'm testing using cromwell-85.jar
The question is the following. I'm developing for using these WDL workflows in the cloud but I need to test locally to make sure it generates the intended output. Is there any option to test the workflow locally using this configuration?
I've tried
java -jar cromwell-85.jar run --inputs input_test_docker.json --options options.json test_docker.wdl 
But it just stays hanging for ever with no error message
I've also tried using the docker image but I get the following warning and I cannot actually use the image in bash mode.
 ~/cromwell$ docker run  -it  docker.io/statisticalgenetics/rap:latest bash WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
I would appreciate any kind of help to try and get this running locally....thank you so much
version 1.0

workflow missGTProcess {

    input {
        Array[File]+ missGT_files
        Int chr
        String dockerImage = "docker.io/statisticalgenetics/rap:latest"
    }

# Call variants in parallel over grouped calling intervals

    scatter (i in range(length(missGT_files))) {
        String file_prefix = basename(missGT_files[i], ".txt")

    call FormatFile {
            input:
             missGT_files = missGT_files[i],
             file_prefix = file_prefix,
             dockerImage=dockerImage
            }
        }

        output {
        Array[File] out = FormatFile.output_varIID
    }
    

    parameter_meta {
        missGT_files: {
            patterns: [".txt"]
        }
    }
}


task FormatFile {
  input {
    Int chr
    File missGT_files
    String dockerImage = "docker.io/statisticalgenetics/rap:latest"
    String file_prefix

  }
  
  command <<<
    set -uexo pipefail
    R --no-save --args ~{missGT_files} ~{file_prefix} <<RSCRIPT
    # Load necessary libraries
    library('data.table')
    print('loading data.table')
    
    RSCRIPT
  >>>

  output {
    File output_varIID = stdout()
  }
  runtime {
        memory: '10G'
        cpu: '2'
        disks: '10GB'
        docker: dockerImage

  }
  parameter_meta {
        missGT_files: {
        help: "Format the txt files to a list of variant and IID to set to missing",
        patterns: [".txt"],
        stream: true,
        localization_optional:true
        }
    }
}

I've tried
java -jar cromwell-85.jar run --inputs input_test_docker.json --options options.json test_docker.wdl 
But it just stays hanging for ever with no error message
I've also tried using the docker image but I get the following warning and I cannot actually use the image in bash mode.
 ~/cromwell$ docker run  -it  docker.io/statisticalgenetics/rap:latest bash WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
I would appreciate any kind of help to try and get this running locally....thank you so much
